# CkEditor conflict with jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor  and trying to submit my form with jquery but I have a conflict
Jquery

```
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(new FormData(this))
            $('.loading-container').show();
                $.ajax({
                url: "store-course-teacher",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,

                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('.loading-container').hide()
                    if(data.status == 'done')
                    {
                        $('#form').hide();
                        $('#add-section').show();
                        $('#course-title').html($('#title').val());
                        $('.course-id').val(data.course_id)

                    }
                }
            });
        }));
    });
```

and from my controller I dumped the result and all text area with ckeditor is `NULL`
I am trying to be clear as possible but that's all I got

Comment: Take off the `processData: false` and see if it changes.

Comment: @Taplar it thorow  `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: Weird.  What sort of form data are you passing to the backend, and how are you trying to access it?  Edit: also try removing the `contentType: false` so jQuery will add the content type to the request

Comment: same error , I am trying to submit a from with description in html

Comment: That doesn't tell me much.  Is the "description" just a textarea?  Is your backend PHP or something else?  Are you trying to access the description with a key off the request?

Comment: yes it's  textarea

Answer (score 1):

I believe with ckeditor, you have to get the HTML from the text editor like this:

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
```

So before calling your ajax, perhaps set data to a hidden input in your form so that your new FormData(this) remains intact?

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
$('#MyHiddenInput').val(data);
```

[More info here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_savedata.html)

Comment: There aren't direct way to send  it with the form ??

Comment: your answer was good, but there are a better solution to send it with form directly.

Answer (score 0):

best way to send ckEditor with the from was updating the ckEditor instanes

```
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
 }
```

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397904/after-ajax-form-submit-value-from-ckeditor-textarea-is-not-sent-through-post/30398137)